# react-native uwp - align text elements in column with right side of label

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-windows

With react-native for windows UWP I have the following JSX:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 5, alignItems: 'stretch' }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text selectable={true} style={{ textAlign: 'right', flex: 1 }}>Average:</Text>
            <Text selectable={true} style={{ flex: 2 }} >&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.averageValue}&nbsp;C</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text selectable={true} style={{ textAlign: 'right', flex: 1 }}>Last:</Text>
            <Text selectable={true} style={{ flex: 2 }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.lastValue}&nbsp;C</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Which lays out the Average and Last text so they're aligned with the colons like so:

[image]

Visually this is what I want, but I can't select the text of an entire line at once.  Only each individual text element is selectable.  If I wrap the two text blocks with an outer text block like this:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text selectable={true}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', flex: 1 }}>Average:</Text>
        <Text style={{ flex: 2 }} >&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.averageValue}&nbsp;C</Text>
    </Text>
</View>
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text selectable={true}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', flex: 1 }}>Last:</Text>
        <Text style={{ flex: 2 }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.lastValue}&nbsp;C</Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

Then my text is selectable like I want, but the layout changes to this:

[image]

How can I get the layout I want and all of the text to be selectable?  Do I have to use explicit widths or can this be done with flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be possible.  The only way to make them all selectable is to wrap them in an outer Text element.  However [text boxes do not participate in Flexbox layout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#containers) so the alignment I want cannot be achieved.

Comment: I could also potentially do this with a fix width font and padding my labels with spaces.